# How can i solve an issue in writing data in specific file in my clr project?

Tags: c++, file, clr

I am trying to add some data to a specific file in my project. I am doing that in the function below.

```
void Files::write_employee(employee employeeObject)
{
    fstream infile;
    infile.open("employeeFile.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);
    string record;
    char delimiter='@';

    record=employeeObject.get_id()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_name()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_password()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_age()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_gender()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_MaritalStatus()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_ministryName()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_departmentName()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_salary()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_photoPath()+delimiter;
    record+=employeeObject.get_photoFileName()+delimiter;
    if (infile.fail())exit(1);
    else {infile<<record;
    infile.close();}
}
```

This function explains how to add data to my file through save the entered data
in an object and save this values in string record and push it to the file.

The big problem is my file which I am trying to add data in, not created yet.
and I don't know why.

thanks in advance.

Comment: try to open the file without using `ios::out`

Comment: thanks for your help, it's working now.

Comment: @Mamoud Elgazzar: You are welcome. See my answer for more information and let us know if that was your problem or something else. Anyhow, you will find a beneficial information down on my answer regarding the file manipulation terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `infile` whereas you are outputting to file. While this does not affect the program code, it makes no sense and break your program readability. Use `outfile` instead.

Remember that it is just like `cout <<` and `cin >>` for the standard I/O.

Also, try not to use `ios::in` when your purpose is only to output to the file and vise versa.

Comment: **infile** is the name of the object from **fstream** class when I removed the next word "ios::out". the project worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to std::fstream::open example at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/), your code is correct and the file must be created. First try to specify an absolute file path to a location that you have write access. If it does not work, print the error message using the following line of code:

```
cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno);
```

Comment: There are many reasons why the file might not be created. The C++ Standard certainly doesn't guarantee that it will be.

Comment: thanks for your help, the project is working now correctly.